# Azure Logic App: Continuation token is not supported for queries with GROUP BY

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use Group By clauses in Azure Logic Apps for querying a single partition which has 1.5m documents.

I can run the query that is coded in the Logic App in the Cosmos Data Explorer without issue:

```
[{
    "AreasProcessed": 1,
    "TotalProperties": 1286,
    "status": 500
},
{
    "AreasProcessed": 45,
    "TotalProperties": 0,
    "status": 400
},
{
    "AreasProcessed": 2275,
    "TotalProperties": 2399469,
    "status": 200
}]
```

However, when I run the query in the Logic App, I get the following error:

```
Continuation token is not supported for queries with GROUP BY. Do not use FeedResponse.ResponseContinuation or remove the GROUP BY from the query.
```

I have enabled Pagination and Asynchronous Pattern on the Logic App.

The full error on the logic app is below, can anyone help me please?

```
{"error": {
    "code": 500,
    "source": "logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "4d6a4cdb-8969-4dd7-b382-90929c7ec829",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
        "status": 500,
        "message": "Continuation token is not supported for queries with GROUP BY. Do not use FeedResponse.ResponseContinuation or remove the GROUP BY from the query.\r\nclientRequestId: 4d6a4cdb-8969-4dd7-b382-90929c7ec829",
        "error": {
            "message": "Continuation token is not supported for queries with GROUP BY. Do not use FeedResponse.ResponseContinuation or remove the GROUP BY from the query."
        },
        "source": "documentdb-we.azconn-we.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, azure team has integrated "**Document Explorer**", "**Query Explorer**", "**Script Explorer**" features as part of "Data Explorer". So "**Data Explorer**" is the best way to do the query. I'm not sure azure logic app uses the same backend with "**Query Explorer**" or "**Document Explorer**", but it seems the logic app doesn't use the same backend with "**Data Explorer**". I think it is the reason why you can run the query in "Data Explorer" on portal but can not run the query in logic app.

For this problem, you can [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function) a azure function and do the query with code in the function. Then [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#create-functions-inside-logic-apps) the function in your logic app. Here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330026/azure-cosmosdb-query-explorer-vs-data-explorer/59390420#59390420) which is similar to your problem(but not same) for your reference.

Comment: Thanks Hury, I've used the Functions method as a workaround and it appears that the SDK which Logic Apps are using to connect to CosmosDB is different to the Data Explorer, I was wondering if anyone else had come up with a better resolution that the Function. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @Weeden Sorry for the delay, I'm not sure if exist a better resolution. Is it possible to implement it without sdk but write the query sql by yourself ?